# how to export (JUnit) test suite as executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, jar

Is there a way in eclipse (Helios) to package/export my JUnit test suites (or maybe even test cases if possible) as executable jars? 
I know how to generate runnable jars from projects with a main class, but i'm clueless about how to include a `TestRunner`.
 Is there a straightforward way, or do I have to make a workaround main class calling the `TestRunner` somehow? 
 Details would be great.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You are correct that a main() method is needed for an executable jar.

It's easy to add a main method to your test suite though.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                    
       JUnitCore.main(
         "com.stackoverflow.MyTestSuite");            
}
```