# executable jar file for junit

Tags: java, unix, executable-jar

i need to run the junit testsuite in unix box. I need make an executable jar file for invoking the test classes. Can any one suggest me how to do create the jar file with the test classes

Comment: It is not any different from making any other kind of executable jar. Don't forget to bundle the JUnit library and you probably need to write a small Main class to invoke the test runner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to export (JUnit) test suite as executable jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar). It seems to cover your question. 
If you don't know how to make a runnable jar, there are several quite easy ways to do that. The most comfortable is from your IDE. If you use eclipse, right-click on your project, select **export** and then, **as runnable jar**.