# How do I create a self contained package of Selenium JUnit Tests?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit

I have a bunch of Selenium Tests which I currently run on JUnit from Eclipse. (Using the Firefox webDriver)
I need to create an easy to install/use package of these tests to give to various members of the QA team so they can run them on different computers.

Is there something that already does this, is there a way to zip up eclipse + tests so they can be run from any computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** there are a couple of ways

I use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for managing the project dependencies and run the tests via sure-fire plugin... but it looks like an overkill for your case

You can see a simple explanintion here:
[how to export (JUnit) test suite as executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar)