# Executing Junit/Selenium tests from a web page

Tags: jsp, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am looking to run my Selenium Junits through a web page(jsp). I can create a simple jsp form , but not sure if my jsp can call my junit. I want this web page to be accesible to other people in the team , so that they can just put my IP where the web page is hosted and run the test , and see the result.
I understand that the browser will not pop up on their system but ll pop out on mine but that is fine, as long as they can see that report that comes out as XML and access screenshots stored on a shared drive.

A sample project , that someone has come across will be great.

Comment: I think this is a nice concept, but I don't think it will be practical. You could try experimenting with applets that would control a service on your machine that would then run the tests for the remote user.. but I don't think it's going to be worth the time if it's only going to have internal use. GL if you try though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/) is a great  solution for your case , this way the jsp is also pre-built. Your tests can be run through a web-browser and its real fast/easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

How about sharing your test code (using source control), so that your team members will be able to run your tests directly on their machines?

Comment: Source control , Eclipse are again a complexity for the manual testers , I was thinking about a solution that works without this complexity

Comment: This is a great opportunity to teach the manual testers some development practices...
I don't think that it's that complicated, after all we are doing it ;)

Comment: See another solution:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045780/how-do-i-create-a-self-contained-package-of-selenium-junit-tests/17064003#17064003