# How can I create jar for test junit testcase?

Tags: java, junit, jar

I read that junit can run without a main() method, but I want to create a jar file for my test. How can I invoke my tests from Main() method? Is there any other way to create jar file for testcases? My code is as follows:

```
public class LoginClass {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://erp.company.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @Test
    public void testERPLogin() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).sendKeys("manju.r");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.oe_attendance_signout")).click();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JUnitCore.main();

[how to export (JUnit) test suite as executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar)

Is a very similar question with the following answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                    
       JUnitCore.main(
         "com.stackoverflow.MyTestSuite");            
}
```

Comment: I got the classNotFoundException :(