# Create Executable Jar for Selenium Code

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, selenium-webdriver

I need to create a Executable Jar file for the Selenium Webdriver Project (TestNG) using Eclipse.

After crawling various website I understand we need to create a Main Class to execute the Test Suite.

I have created a Main Class with below code.

```
package com.testcases;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
     Class[] classes = new Class[]{
             Abc.class,
             PQR.class,
             XYZ.class
             };
     testng.setTestClasses(classes);
     testng.addListener(tla);
     testng.run();
    }
}
```

When, I have created a runnable Jar using Export->Java->Runnable Jar from Selenium, and after running through jar file using command prompt with below command:

```
java -jar AbcXyz.jar
```

Program Execution get into the Infinite loop

Please help for creating such Executable Jar file.

Below are some References:
Testng

Comment: Did you create any method to stop test? I think you should.

Comment: I am still in process to create such a Main class file for the Project. Kindly, help for the same.. The Classes Abc.java, pqr.java and xyz.java are purely TestNG files and does not consists Main file.

Comment: does testNG file runs properly?

Comment: Yes - The TestNG file with Main() runs successfully.

Comment: cant you run the jar file as TestNG test directly ?

Comment: Are the tests in a infinite loop or are they just hanging because you didn't call quit on the driver instances?

Comment: A possible duplicate ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar

Answer (score 0):

Did you end your tests with
`driver.quit();`

This could be the reason

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?