# How to create runnable jar file for junit using eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit4, executable-jar

Here it is my code:
        package JUnit;
        import org.junit.Test;

```
     public class first {
         @Test
         public void testOne(){
             System.out.println("Executing first test");
         }
     }
```

I want to create jar file of this class.Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/423938/983430), for instance?

Comment: right click on project and export as jar. There would be option to make exported jar executable too but as your class does not have main method it will not execute on double click.

Comment: Want to create batch file

Comment: Yes, Naveen u r right...but I have written program in JUnit and main method is not present in JUnit

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar It seems to cover your question.