# How can I export JUnit test cases into an executable .jar?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am using Selenium and JUnit to automate some testing. I want to be able to export this into a runnable jar file. I was not able to and I am assuming it is because there is no main method, JVM doesn't know what to run....

I saw this post [how to export (JUnit) test suite as executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4648341/8854270) and it suggested adding a main and running the JUnit from there. (I would have commented on that post, but it didn't let me )

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore.main("folder.package.testClass");
}
```

I made a new java class with this main method in it but the test class is never executed (from eclipse). Also if I try to export the project, I get errors and it doesn't export.

For my purposed of exporting all the JUnit classes into 1 Jar file and running from there, what the best way I could do this? I might event build a small menu where the user can pick which test class they want to run (which I'm assuming will require a main method some where....).

Comment: it might be reason of wrong exporting. First, ensure that you are creating valid executable jar(with some print line or etc)

Comment: It doesn't run from eclipse too.. but the export doesn't work, I know that's broken

Comment: let's focus into problem of execution. I believe you are sure that problem is there

Comment: Yes, I tired the code above, I also tried the code provided here https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/unit-testing/junit/junit-core.html

The Java class runs, but it never accesses the JUnit class and it never runs it.

Comment: example provided in the link requires you to point to a test suite class not a package. Is "folder.package.testClass"? is a path to the test suite class?

Comment: I will make a new project that is a test suite and try again (on monday when I'm back at work =))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code ended up working for me.

```
package myPackageName;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class testRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can execute test by doing following(just checked current scenario):

1. Create new Eclipse *Java project*
2. Add junit and hamcrest jars to your build path(I'm using *junit-4.12* and *hamcrest-core-1.3*). It should look:

[image]

3. Create your test under *test* folder:

   ```
   package com.example.junit5;

   import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

   import org.junit.Test;

   public class FirstTest {

       @Test
       public void testTrue() {
           System.out.println("Executing testTrue()");
           assertTrue(true);     
        }
   }
   ```
4. Create your main(executor) class under *src* folder:

   ```
   package com.example.junit5;

   import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

   public class Executor {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           JUnitCore.main("com.example.junit5.FirstTest");
       }

   }
   ```
5. Execute your test as *Java Application*. **Result should be:**

[image]

My environment config is:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Hope this will help